# Using ImageMagick with Cronjob Commandline paths

Tags: command-line, cron, imagemagick

I have the following code to update a graphical map with ImageMagick commandline. It works fine when run directly from the website, but I am attempting to schedule it via a cronjob. It doesn't appear to be finding the images in the $m string that I build - I think due to a path issue? The full server path used in `if (file_exists(...))` works, but I have tried the actual ImageMagick commend line with both full server path and local path and doesn't seem to work. Any ideas what Im doing wrong here?

```
$icon_on_map_fullpath = "/home/site/public_html/media/icon_on_map/";
$icon_on_map_path = "../media/icon_on_map/";

foreach($map_clusters as $mc) {
        
    $icon_name = $mc['cluster_id'].'.png';
        
    if (file_exists($icon_on_map_fullpath.$icon_name)) {
            $m .= $icon_on_map_path.$icon_name." -geometry +".$mc['clus_x']."+".$mc['clus_y']." -composite ";
    }

}

exec("convert master_map.png {$m} lastest_map.png ");
```

Comment: 1) what s the curent directory when run form cron, and 2) what is the assumed user when run from cron and has it got adequate access rights to the files

Comment: Hi xenoid. Thanks for your help. Im not 100% sure what you mean by #1. The full cron command is /usr/local/bin/php /home/site/public_html/process/update_map.php. What files should I look for permissions on. The images that are being accessed and changed? If so the folder is 755 and the image itself is 644

Comment: I mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). In your `convert` command, there are two path-less file names (`master_map.png` and `lastest_map.png` (did you mean `latest` btw?)), so the first must be in the WD and the second will be  created in the WD, wherever that is. So either you set the WD, or you use full paths.